# Smtplib error when emaling to a yahoo.com domain

Tags: python-3.x, smtp, smtplib

**Problematic Snippet**

```
    server = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com' if 'yahoo.com' in mail else 'smtp.gmail.com'
    port = 465 if 'yahoo.com' in mail else 587
            
    with smtplib.SMTP(server, port) as connection:
        connection.starttls()
        connection.login(MY_EMAIL, PASSWORD)
        connection.sendmail(
            from_addr=MY_EMAIL,
            to_addrs=mail,
            msg=f'Subject: Happy Birthday\n\n{reformatted_template}'
```

When it comes to gmail domains, everything works fine. But when emailing to a yahoo domain, it throws this error:

```
    smtplib.SMTPConnectError: (-1, b'\x02\x01Z\x15\x03\x03\x00\x02\x01\x00')
```

Gone through so many threads as to how to fix this, but none have worked. Some of them are:

- using smtplib.SMTP_SSL instead of smtplib.SMTP
- changing the port to 465
- checking for typos (MY_EMAIL and PASSWORD check out)

When I used smtplib.SMTP_SSL, this error is thrown instead:

```
    smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

I really appreciate the help in advance, can't wait to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

```
server = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com' if 'yahoo.com' in mail else 'smtp.gmail.com'
port = 465 if 'yahoo.com' in mail else 587
        
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(server, port) as connection: #changeed to SMTP_SSL
    #connection.starttls() #this is not needed
    connection.login(MY_EMAIL, PASSWORD)
    connection.sendmail(
        from_addr=MY_EMAIL,
        to_addrs=mail,
        msg=f'Subject: Happy Birthday\n\n{reformatted_template}'
```

An app password should also be defined in yahoo and gmail for this to work (careful, yahoo app and google app won't give you the same password).

Comment: But this won't work for Gmail because they don't use `SMTP_SSL`. You need to split up things even more.

Comment: You're right @triplee. Only tested with yahoo.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct connection method for each server also.

```
server, port, connect_method = (
    'smtp.mail.yahoo.com', 465, smtplib.SMTP_SSL) if 'yahoo.com' in mail else (
    'smtp.gmail.com', 587, smtplib.SMTP)

with connect_method(server, port) as connection:
    if port == 587:
        connection.starttls()
    connection.login(MY_EMAIL, PASSWORD)
    connection.sendmail(...)
```

In so many words, legacy port 465 uses `SMTP_SSL` to create an encrypted connection right from the start. Modern port 587 uses clear text up until `starttls()` and then pivots to encrypted on both server and client from that point on.  The error message you see is the encrypted response from Yahoo's server which speaks TLS when you connect to it.  And of course, when talking TLS already, `starttls()` does not make sense.

Tangentially, don't create email messages by pasting strings together; use the `email` library (and probably graduate to `smtplib.send_message` which requires a modern `EmailMessage` object, not the legacy `email.Message` or its `MIMEText` etc brethren).